# Practicality of using flat-spiral coil as electromagnet?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetic, proximity-sensor

For my project, I'm using a 3D magnetic sensor to track the proximity of a local electromagnet at any time, no more than a finger length away.

Ideally, I would like the the electromagnet to be:

- between 5-10mm radius
- flat, with a height below < 5mm, lower the better
- be able to produce a magnetic field strong enough that my 3D magnetic sensor (BNO055) can pick up within range of 5-7cm.

Something like this, but assuming my qualifications:

[image]

---

1. With this in consideration, is this possible or practical having an electromagnet this small and powerful enough to produce the necessary field?

---

2. Bad question, but from what I've researched, an inductor is an essentially a single coil wrapped around a core, so it is by definition an electromagnet when a current passes through it. That being said I've looked online attempting to find one to buy, and I've come across strikingly different looking inductors, making me question if I actually understand what an inductor is. [This fixed inductor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZ65NJS) is the same as the image above (besides being axial, radial, or ..etc) and both will produce a magnetic field when a current is passed through?

---

3. If I'm missing something altogether or if anyone has any recommendations related or otherwise please comment, I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: *"n = 2, i = 5V = 10A, l (height in this case) = 3mm, r = 5mm, The E field would = 8377.58 microteslas"* this sounds like good old fashioned mumbo jumbo.

Comment: 10A is a pretty huge amount of current for this application. Why not wind yourself a coil of suitable shape and try it with the sensor? I suggest starting with no more than 500mA, and using an AC drive for the coil to make it easier to spot the signal on the sensor.

Comment: Edit: **i = 40mA I'm using an Arduino. @pcj50 I'm trying to implement this on a small microcontroller, from what I just looked up, an AC drive looks pretty large and an overkill for my application, is this absolutely necessary?

Comment: The website you have used will not calculate fields if length is less than radius so what did you glean from that website and did you not see the warning about this?

Comment: @Andyaka "Also note that the formula used for (inductance) is valid only when the coil length is significantly larger than the radius." It does not say anything about magnetic field calculations. And my question really has nothing to do with this, even considering that 1 line of my post, your comments still aren't productive or helpful.

Comment: You said "I appreciate any feedback" and I'm giving you feedback. If it does correctly calculate a field then that field (not called an E field incidentally) will be at the mouth of the coil and not at some point in space a few cm away. At 5-7 cm away it will be significantly smaller. Have you tried to make a coil and test this for yourself?

Comment: @Andyaka fair. I've experimented with solenoids on larger scales, but I've found it difficult to create it being this small and when winding it flat.

Comment: Why does it need to be wound flat BTW?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm trying to reproduce this essentially - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHhbM_2UMiI - but large electromagnets are pretty clunky, I was thinking a flat coil would reduce the bulkiness of the electromagnets at each tracking point on each finger, but from testing different numbers on that website with what I know now from your answer, it doesnt seem like its going to get any less bulky.

Comment: If you are going down that route then I don't see a need for a spiral wind. The inner turns of the spiral hardly produce any magnetism at all. Plus, if you are going to apply AC (as per the video) then you might need fewer turns because inductance will act as an AC block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87038/discussion-between-dante-biase-and-andy-aka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) With this in consideration, is this possible or practical having an
>   electromagnet this small and powerful enough to produce the necessary
>   field?

Taken from [this website](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html), the following picture explains that with 2 turns (as originally specified) and 40 mA current, the magnetic field density at 5 cm from the coil is about 10 nT: -

[image]

With 5 turns (as recently specified), the flux density will be 5 times larger at 50 nT.

> 2) so it is by definition an electromagnet when a current passes through
>   it.

An inductor produces a magnetic field when current passes through its coils.

Comment: I've provided you with a sample calculation based on what you previously said about the coil and current **AND** the means to evaluate any new coil you might consider with the link to the hyperphysics website. Your #1 question is: *With this in consideration, is this possible or practical having an electromagnet this small and powerful enough to produce the necessary field?* So what is it that you might be asking that isn't covered in my answer pray tell?

Comment: I clearly didn't understanding what I was calculating. This clears it up, I can solve my first question on my own now. Thank you for this and your patience and help.